# Removing an if statement changes the datatype of a promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

So I am fairly new to Typescript, and I am not quite sure what is happening here. I am building an Ionic App and so in my providers folder, I have the one provider. In two of my functions, if I remove an if statement at the starting of them, I get an error on the TypeScript file for my homepage that says

```
type '{}' is not assignable to type '[]'
```

But when I add the if statement, it doesn't give that error anymore.

```
getOneCourse(course){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
        this.http.post('http:localhost:8080/api/specificCourse', JSON.stringify(course), {headers: headers})
        .map(res=> res.json())
        .subscribe(data=>{
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

This is one of those functions without the if statement, and my typescript homepage file corresponding function is:

```
searchCourse(){
  let modal=this.ModalCtrl.create(CoursePage);
  modal.onDidDismiss(course=>{
    if(course)
    this.courseService.getOneCourse(course).then((data)=>{
      if(typeof(data[0]) === "undefined"){
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: "oops",
          buttons: ["ok"]
        });
      }
      console.log(data);
      this.specificCourses= data;
    });
  });
  modal.present()
  }
```

where I initiate specificCourses = []; earlier.

My second function in my provider file is:

```
getCourses(){
    if (this.data){
        return Promise.resolve(this.data)
    }
    else{
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/courses')
        .map(res=> res.json())
        .subscribe(data=>{
            this.data = data;
            resolve(this.data);

        });
    });
}
}
```

It is that initial

```
if(this.data){
return Promise.resolve(this.data)}
```

that is causing this. What is so pivotal about that if statement? Thanks guys and let me know if you need any more info.

EDIT: I should add, when I add the if statement to the getOneCourse() function, it doesn't only give me one course, but returns all of them. Any ideas why that could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Service make sure you're importing the correct HTTP

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Make sure this is also reflected in your main app.module as well

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

And in the imports section in your main app.module

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
]
```

In your service change the getOneCourse to:

```
getOneCourse(course: any): Promise<any> {
  let data = JSON.stringify(course);
  headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
  return this.http.post('http:localhost:8080/api/specificCourse', data, {headers: headers}).toPromise();
}
```

and from your component page you can call it like this:

```
searchCourse() {

  let modal=this.ModalCtrl.create(CoursePage);
  modal.present();

  modal.onWillDismiss((course: any) => {
    if(course) {
      this.courseService.getOneCourse(course)
       .then((response) => {
         if(typeof(response[0]) === "undefined"){
           let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
             title: "oops",
             buttons: ["ok"]
           });
         }
         console.log(response);
         this.specificCourses= response;
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.log('Error response ', JSON.stringify(error));
       });
    }
  });
}
```

For your courses function you can follow a similar set up:

```
getCourses(): Promise<any[]> {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/courses').toPromise();
}
```